# Q: Can I do a screen record in Selenium using JS?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to record my screen while my tests are running.
I saw http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.com/2013/03/screen-recording-video-of-java-webdiver.html
But the code here is in Java and I need something in JS.
Can I do the screen record in JavaScript? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible. Please check [this](https://github.com/presidenten/wdio-video-reporter) this page for more details.